# Kivy Clock unscheduling issue

Tags: python, kivy

I'm currently struggling to fully utilize the kivy's clock unschedule operations. I'm assigning a schedule for a callback upon pressing a key. I have achieved executing the scheduled callback, however what I also wish to do is once a key is pressed, not only will it initiate a callback, it will also cancel any existing ones. My issue is that although I have coded an event.cancel(), the event isn't canceled at all. The entire program is a bit large, but I can show code in which the clock is used directly.

```
def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    event0 = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self.pressHome(), 3)
    event1 = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self.selectFig(coord = 'A2'), 2)
    event2 = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self.selectFig(coord = 'A3'), 4)

    if keycode[1] == 'd':
        coord = 'A3'
        self.selectFig(coord)
        event1()
        event2()
        event0.cancel()

    elif keycode[1] == 'f':
        coord = 'A4'
        self.selectTxt(coord)

        event1.cancel()
        event2.cancel()
        event0()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating **new** events every time, thus you are **not** canceling the old ones

A possible fix might be creating the triggers only **once**:

```
def __init__(self, **kw):
    self.event0 = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self.pressHome(), 3)
    self.event1 = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self.selectFig(coord = 'A2'), 2)
    self.event2 = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self.selectFig(coord = 'A3'), 4)

def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    event0 = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self.pressHome(), 3)
    event1 = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self.selectFig(coord = 'A2'), 2)
    event2 = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self.selectFig(coord = 'A3'), 4)

    if keycode[1] == 'd':
        coord = 'A3'
        self.selectFig(coord)
        self.event1()
        self.event2()
        self.event0.cancel()

    elif keycode[1] == 'f':
        coord = 'A4'
        self.selectTxt(coord)

        self.event1.cancel()
        self.event2.cancel()
        self.event0()
```

Comment: It worked! Why is it that the triggers need to be within the constructor? Although they were initially made within _on_keyboard_down, they aren't called until an event() activates it.

Comment: Because you need to cancel the same events, not the new ones that are created each time you call the ** _on_keyboard_down** method